# how to get an output of next `ten` odd and even numbers after entering any random number in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to have a logic where if I enter an even number I want next 10 even numbers to be printed and If I enter an odd number, I want next 10 odd numbers to be printed. How should I rectify this logic inside a function. If someone can please help me rectifying the logic which was answered.

`JS`

```js
function oddEven() {
var input = prompt("");
for (let x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
  console.log(input + x * 2);
}
}
oddEven()
```

Comment: `0 % 2 === 0` you don't need extra logic for the `0` case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for any number

```
const input = 2
for (let x = 1; x <= 10; x += 1) {
 console.log(input + x * 2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let inputval = 2;
for (let x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
  console.log(inputval + x * 2)
}
```

Comment: this logic works for me and if you can please let me know how can i use this logic if i want it inside a `function` where I can input a number after a `prompt`

Comment: Please show in your answer: How can user20086268 get from `prompt("please enter an integral number:")` to a number to pass to a function?

Answer (score 0):

i hope this help

```
function printTen(input){
  let list = []
  let number = input
  while(list.length <= 10){
    number++
    if(input % 2 === 0 && number % 2 === 0){
      console.log(number +  " is even");
      list.push(number)
    }else if(input % 2 !== 0 && number % 2 !== 0) {
      console.log(number +  " is odd");
      list.push(number)
      
    }
  }
}

printTen(9)
```